# Joining two edittext strings together in eclipse adt

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to android developing and am adapting the first eclipse tutorial..

What syntax do I need to 1) send editAmount and editTag edittext boxes to an array, so that I can then call each of them individually and 2) concatenate them to a single string named 'message'?

I'm trying to work out what I should replace .' and '. with in the below code:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void SubmitReceipt(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_amount);
    EditText editTag = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_tag);
    String message = editAmount.getText().toString().' and '.editTag.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: If you just want to add two Strings just `+` to join them. If anything else then specify clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to concatenate them then just use `+`:

```
String message = editAmount.getText().toString() + editTag.getText().toString();
```

If you want to add some strings in between them,

```
String message = editAmount.getText().toString() +"and"+ editTag.getText().toString();
```

**Edit:**

**Method1**: If you want to just send one message from your first activity but then recognize the two of them separately in next, use `delimiters`. Add delimiter (lets say `;` here and then in the next activity use `.split` to split them and save them in array.

**Method 2:** You can send two of them separately and then save them in array in next activity

Comment: he doesn't just want to concat but also want to make recognize these two string later differently later or am I guessing the question incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks @RohanKandwal for pointing it out. 
Simeon: Hope this is what you were trying to ask.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Welcome and OP please ask the question clearly from next time.

Comment: Thanks. Is it better to use method 1 or 2 in your view? (I'm trying to eventually work out how I might update a database from the form)

Comment: It depends if you want to save those values in database seperately or together. In any case in your second activity, you are separating both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Join using a separator ("," in this case), to easily separate the strings again:

```
String message = String.format("%s,%s", editAmount.getText().toString(), editTag.getText().toString());
```